# H-1B renewal: 240 days rule implications

Tags: usa, h1-visa, uscis

I am puzzled about this extract from the USCIS H-1B information page.

> By law, the timely filing of an extension request automatically “locks in” the foreign national’s legal status and ability to work for the sponsoring employer for a period of 240 days beyond the date upon which the H-1B status expires.

It clearly states that the rule grants you the ability to keep working for your sponsoring employer but what else does it actually "locks in" implies:

- Does it imply that you cannot change employers during that time, even after getting the   visa extension?
- Does it imply that you cannot change your legal status (like to married, or father) during that time.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have a link for the page from USCIS? The only place I found the sentence was on [a third party website](https://www.immi-usa.com/h1b-visa/h1b-visa-extension/)

Comment: The legal status they're speaking of is _lawful immigration status._  It has nothing to do with any other legal status such as marital status or other family relationships.

Answer (score 1):

This page talks about extending the H1b status beyond the statutory limit of maximum of 6 years. This is only available for people who have a pending I-140 petition or AOS pending for more than a year.

What the quote says is that under these circumstances, filing an H1b extension extends your legal status for another 240 days (more specifically, extends your employment authorization for the same employer: here's [the official rule](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/8/274a.12#b_20)). That is your *immigration* status. I.e.: your H1b status.

You can change employers (once the extension is approved), but since you have an I140/AOS pending you should do that considering your immigration petition. If the employer cancels your pending I140 petition, you will no longer be eligible for H1b extensions since you're more than 6 years in the status in this scenario and no longer have an immigration petition pending. There are conditions under which you can move to a new employer *with* the immigration petition ([AC21 rules](https://www.immi-usa.com/ac21-portability-rule/)), but you need to be aware of what and how you're doing in order to not screw that up.

Comment: "filing an H1b extension extends your legal status for another 240 days" It doesn't, because a pending application never gives you "status". Only if the extension of status application is approved, are you retroactively considered to have been in status.

Comment: well... I'm explaining the text provided, I'm not actually sure if there's an explicit 240 days rule (what if the extension request is not processed within 240 days?)

Comment: There is an explicit 240 days of employment authorization for people with pending worker status extensions, in [8 CFR 274a.12(b)(20)](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/8/274a.12#b_20). If it is still pending after 240 days, they can no longer work. They can of course still stay in the US, as they have a pending Extension of Stay or Change of Status application.

Comment: @user102008 thanks, added the link to the answer